# Group elements in XSLT even if grouping key is missing

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I have the following XML:

```
<cars>
  <car type='toyota'>
   <model>Yaris</model>
   <year>1998</year>
   <company>TOYOTA</company>
  </car>
  <car type='kia'>
   <model>Optima</model>
   <year>2002</year>
   <company>KIA</company>
  </car>
  <car type='kia'>
   <model>CERATO</model>
   <year>2009</year>
   <company>KIA</company>
  </car>
  <car type='bmw'>
   <model>M3</model>
   <year>2016</year>
   <company>BMW</company>
  </car>
  <car type='bmw'>
   <model>X5</model>
   <year>2010</year>
  </car>
  <car type='bmw'>
   <model>335i</model>
   <year>2010</year>
   <company>BMW</company>
  </car>
 </cars>
```

I want to group the cars by company element with sorting (alpha, ascending) on the same element. the output should be something like:

```
BMW: M3, X5, 335i
KIA: Optima, CERATO
TOYOTA: Yaris
```

The thing is that the car element might not contain a company node, In this case the car/@type value must be used to add the element to the correct group. How can I map the value of the @type attribute to the correct group that is based on the company value?

Comment: Show us your existing grouping and sorting code so that we can fix it, it is not that difficult to use `group-by="(company, upper-case(@type))[1]"` for instance.

Comment: And tag or advise which XSLT version you use in attempted code.

Comment: In your example the `COMPANY` element is redundant since when present it's always equal to `upper-case(@type)`, so why not just ignore it and group on `@type`?

Comment: I missed an important part in my example. The value of the company isn't always the same as the value of type. Also, the value of type might not be present in one of the company elements and in that case, a new group should be rendered with the value of type and the relevant elements.

Comment: Im using XSLT v2. 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little know feature of XSLT (at least in version 2.0) is
that when you create a list, e.g. `(xx, yy, zz)`, this list
actually containts **only existing values**.
If e.g. `xx` value was empty, it would not be a part of the
result list.

So if you write `[1]` after it, you actually get **the first
non-empty element** from the expression list between parentheses.

In your comment, as of 5.08, you asked for a solution that `other` type
shoud be treated as `TOYOTA`.
It is possible, using `if ... then ... else ...`, in this case:
*if (@type = 'other') then 'TOYOTA' else @type*

So you can write the script the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="cars">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="car" group-by="upper-case(
      (company, if (@type = 'other') then 'TOYOTA' else @type)[1])">
      <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="string-join(current-group()/model, ', ')"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

As you can see:

- `(company, if (@type = 'other') then 'TOYOTA' else @type)`
  is the source list (argument of *upper-case*),
- `[1]` takes first element from what has been created.

I moved the call to `upper-case` to the "outer level",
assuming that `model` can also be written in lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. what if I had a car with type='other' and no company.
In that case, I want it to display as part of e.g. "TOYOTA" as a default fallback value. Is that even possible?

Comment: I changed the solution, so it works as you wished (*type = 'other' is taken as 'TOYOTA'*).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much.